# Navigation Drawer : Custom selected object background

Tags: android, android-listview, navigation-drawer

I would like to reproduce this effect when i select an item in my navigation drawer menu :

[image]

How can i do that ?

I would like to have on the left a little blue banier and on the right a dark background.

Answer (score 0):

create a selector with different drawable images to indicate the different states. That specific state you want is the activated state but you also need to cover the other states too.

an example of a selector would be like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_price_normal_market" android:state_enabled="true" 
    android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_price_pressed_market" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_price_focused_market" android:state_focused="true"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: Yes, i started to create a selector and attach it to my listview. But, how can i create a part in blue on the left and another part in dark color in background ?

Comment: another option is to create a custom adapter with a layout with the blue line in it but hidden until the row is clicked. then update the adapter and show the blue line when it is. that is probably the route I would go

Comment: Use a NinePatch drawable. You can have the blue part on the left, and the rest of with your new background colour.